# Adding a highscore

Tags: python

I am pretty new to coding in Python and coding in general and ive been working on a schoolproject. In this project you need to code a game. Now im am pretty far already but ive been trying to add a highscore but its just not coming to work, here is my code:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
 
pygame.init()


white = (255, 255, 255)
yellow = (255, 255, 102)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (213, 50, 80)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (50, 153, 213)

dis_width = 400
dis_height = 500
 
dis = pygame.display.set_mode((dis_width, dis_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('SNELIAS')
 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
snake_block = 10
snake_speed = 8


font_style = pygame.font.SysFont("bahnschrift", 25)
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 35)
 
 
def Your_score(score):
    value = score_font.render("Your Score: " + str(score), True, yellow)
    dis.blit(value, [0, 0])
 
def High_score(score):
    value = score_font.render("Highscore: " + str(score), True, yellow)
    dis.blit(value, [0, 0])

def our_snake(snake_block, snake_list):
    for x in snake_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, black, [x[0], x[1], snake_block, snake_block])
 
 
def message(msg, color):
    mesg = font_style.render(msg, True, color)
    dis.blit(mesg, [dis_width / 6, dis_height / 3])
 
 
def gameLoop():
    game_over = False
    game_close = False
 
    x1 = dis_width / 2
    y1 = dis_height / 2
 
    x1_change = 0
    y1_change = 0
 
    snake_List = []
    Length_of_snake = 1
    Score_high = 0 
    foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
    foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0

    image = pygame.image.load("snakegrnd.jpeg")
    screenUpdate = pygame.transform.scale(image, (dis_width, dis_height))


    while not game_over:
        dis.blit(screenUpdate, (0, 0))
      
        while game_close == True:
            message("You Lost! Press C-Play Again or Q-Quit", white)
            Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
            if High_score < Length_of_snake - 1:
              High_score = Length_of_snake - 1
              High_score(High_score)
            pygame.display.update()


          
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        game_over = True
                        game_close = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()
 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x1_change = -snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x1_change = snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y1_change = -snake_block
                    x1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y1_change = snake_block
                    x1_change = 0
 
        
        if x1 + x1_change > dis_width:
          x1 = 0
        if x1 + x1_change < 0:
          x1 = dis_width
        if y1 + y1_change > dis_height:
          y1 = 0
        if y1 + y1_change < 0:
          y1 = dis_height
      
        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, red, [foodx, foody, snake_block, snake_block])
        snake_Head = []
        snake_Head.append(x1)
        snake_Head.append(y1)
        snake_List.append(snake_Head)
        if len(snake_List) > Length_of_snake:
            del snake_List[0]
 
        for x in snake_List[:-1]:
            if x == snake_Head:
                game_close = True
 
        our_snake(snake_block, snake_List)
        Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
 
        pygame.display.update()
 
        if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 1
 
        clock.tick(snake_speed)
 
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
 
 
gameLoop()
```

if anyone has an idea please let me know because all the parts where highscore is placed has done nothing. If you have additional changes be my guest. :)

i have tried copying the code of "your score" because that does work.

Comment: I answered for the one, extremely obvious problem. If you're having other issues, you need to include a description of what you expect to happen and what is actually happening as part of a [MCVE]. "Does not work" is thoroughly useless.

Comment: i said does not work because it does not work, it does nothing, literally nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you're using the right variables**

At the beginning of `gameLoop` you define a variable called `Score_high`. Then later you a variable named `High_score` which is the function you defined earlier not the `Score_high` variable. Try changing:

```
        while game_close == True:
            message("You Lost! Press C-Play Again or Q-Quit", white)
            Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
            if High_score < Length_of_snake - 1:
              High_score = Length_of_snake - 1
              High_score(High_score)
            pygame.display.update()
```

to:

```
while game_close == True:
            message("You Lost! Press C-Play Again or Q-Quit", white)
            Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
            if Score_high < Length_of_snake - 1:
              Score_high = Length_of_snake - 1
              High_score(Score_high)
            pygame.display.update()
```

(This is a great example of why good naming practices are extremely important. You should name the function that shows the highscore something like `show_highscore`, and name the variable that holds the highscore `highscore`.)

Comment: I have changed it but it still doesnt display the highscore, and now the message "You Lost! Press C-Play Again or Q-Quit" doesnt display. Still thanks for the tip